# User object not iterable when using exclude

Tags: python, django

My function:

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
def SearchView(request):
    query = request.GET.get("search")
    # if query:
    profile = User.objects.filter(
    Q(is_client=True,first_name__icontains=query) |
    Q(is_client=True,last_name__icontains=query)

    ).exclude(request.user).distinct()
    hub = Hub.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=query)
    )
    task = Task.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query),
    )
    results = list(
            chain(profile, hub, task))
            # key=lambda objects: objects.created_at
    paginator = Paginator(results, 5)  # Show 5 contacts per page
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
    notifications = Notification.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)

    context = {
        'profile':profile,
        'page_request_var':page_request_var,
        'contacts': contacts,

    }


    return render(request,'search.html',context)
```

I want the search results to exclude current user. The users are sent as profile.The problem is ,when i use exclude, Its showing error "User object is not iterable" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exclude`, like `filter`, takes a filter expression. You can't just pass an object; it needs a lookup and a value. So you could do:

```
.exclude(id=request.user.id)
```